# OAuth - Facebook custom authorization grant

Tags: oauth, rest, facebook

I've developed my own custom authorization grant.

The steps I am undertaking are the following:

1. I get the facebook authorization code from the mobile device (this is an an API for mobile devices)
2. I exchange the auth code for a Facebook access token using curl. I save access token in the database and associate it with a user that I created using the facebook data (api('/me'))
3. I return the access token to the mobile device
4. Mobile device makes a POST request to my oauth endpoint providing the access token. At this stage, I take the access token from the form, validate it as a string, inspect it using the Facebook Graph API (with curl) to make sure the app id and user id match and then look it up on my database. If a row exists, I check whether the associated user's email matches the email provided in the POST data along with the token. If it matches, I return the user_id and generate my app-specific token using oauth.

All of this is done in an HTTPS environnment.

Is this considered to be secure?

**EDIT**: I ended up using [this](https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel) package for Laravel. I still need to create a user with the facebook data on my database, but the authentication part is now handled by the package.

Comment: Doesn't oauth have a model for you to use?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you're referring to the authorization grant, then no, it doesn't apply here. I had to implement my own one. Is it secure though?

Comment: OAuth is used by many services. They all have authorization grants. Have you investigated their models?

Comment: No, I haven't. The method I came up with is specific to the implementation of the API I'm developing, but in general, it should be common.

Comment: All I'm doing is getting the Facebook access token, returning it to the user and letting him/her POST data to my oauth route in order to issue him/her the application-specific access token.

Comment: I've implemented the manual login flow as outlined in the Facebook docs.

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.
Is your goal only authenticating the user to your API using the users facebook account?

Comment: Yes. I've implemented the manual login flow as outlined in the facebook website.

Comment: The steps I've written in the question are taken from this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0#exchangecode

Comment: The authorization grant doesn't apply here, because it generates the authcode on my server. This is obviously not the case in my situation (not what I'm trying to achieve). I'm receiving the authcode from facebook and exchanging it for an access token.

Comment: I've edited my post.